# Apache2 won't start after 14.04 update

Tags: server, apache2

I try to restart my apache2 using :

```
# sudo service apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2                                                   *
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ruby.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ruby.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ruby.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Reinstall mod_ruby with `apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruby`.  Does the error still occur?

Comment: @eyoung100 that package seems to have vanished after 13.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-ruby

Comment: Tried - recieved error:
root@web:~# apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-ruby is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-ruby' has no installation candidate
root@web:~#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libapache2-mod-ruby` package is no longer available in Ubuntu 14.04. It was dropped in Ubuntu 13.10. From the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-ruby/+changelog):

> Deleted in saucy-release (Reason: upstream project dead, requires substantial upstream port...)

You should disable or remove the module if you don't needed it (or look for other options such as building from source). To disable the module:

```
sudo a2dismod ruby
# or 
sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ruby.load
```

Thanks to [@eyoung100's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530167/apache2-wont-start-after-14-04-update/530175#comment723514_530175), there's a new project started at https://github.com/mikeowens/mod_ruby. The old project, at https://github.com/shugo/mod_ruby, is clearly long dead.

Comment: The source module is [available here](https://github.com/mikeowens/mod_ruby)  Muru beat me to the correct answer by Googling faster :)

Comment: @eyoung100 That's a new project. The original is at https://github.com/shugo/mod_ruby (which you can see is long dead).

Comment: @eyoung100 it's not a fork (started from scratch) but that's a nitpick. Thanks, updated the answer. :)

Comment: Cool - thank you I am now able to start apache - now on to moving my websites so those load in the new path